# Joining 2 csv files in OS X

Tags: csv, terminal

I want to join 2 csv files, e.g.

```
A,B
1,2
```

and

```
C,D
1,3
```

to

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,1,3
```

I had tried it out with

> cat *.csv >merged.csv

But it doesnt reach the goal, that I want.
 Can anyone helps me

Answer (score 3):

`cat` stands for concatenate, it prints the 1st file and then the content of 2nd file after it not next to it. So using `cat` you cant achieve your output:

```
$ cat *.csv
A,B
1,2
C,D
1,3
$
```

You can use the `paste` command which paste's lines from 2 files side by side i.e line 1 from file 1 is pasted before line 1 from file 2.

```
$ cat file1.csv 
A,B
1,2
$ cat file2.csv 
C,D
1,3
$ paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv > newfile.csv
$ cat newfile.csv
A,B,C,D
1,2,1,3
$
```

`-d ,` means delimiter must be comma.

Comment: I had tried it out, but it doesnt work. The Error was paste: illegal option -- -
usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...

Comment: why doesn't it work? .. can you edit your question and post your error?

Comment: try to use `paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv`

Comment: Yeah, Thx.i had tried it with -d. But how can i paste it into a new csv file?

Comment: No problem .. kindly accept the answer by clicking on tick beside the answer :)